# MFC - CArray copy

Tags: c++, mfc

I have two arrays filled with integers.

The equal operator can not be used as the compiler is giving one error.

The source code is below. Please help.

```cpp
CArray <int, int&> temp;
CArray <int, int&> definition;
    
definition = temp;
```

The error is the following:

> error [C2280](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280?view=msvc-170): `CArray<int,int &> &CArray<int,int &>::operator =(const CArray<int,int &> &)`: attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: And CArray does not implement a copy constructor (no idea why not). use : [CArray::Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class?view=msvc-170#copy). Or just refactor your code to std::vector if you can.

Comment: Use [`CArray::Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class#copy) instead.

Comment: Why are you using MFC container classes in this day and age, when even the Microsoft engineers do not use them (any more).  The `std::vector` is standard and IMO far superior to CArray.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `std::vector` stops being superior if serialization is a requirement. I wonder where you got your information from that *"Microsoft engineers do not use them"*.

Comment: I can't find the source right now, but it stated that the applications that are C++ based that Microsoft developed no longer (or do not) use MFC containers.  The one exception was `CString`.

Comment: That's the *assignment* operator.

Comment: @molbdnilo CArray doesn't support assignment operator either :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`CArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class) class template derives from [`CObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cobject-class). The latter declares its copy constructor and assignment operator as private, and `CArray` necessarily inherits those properties. Any attempt to use either results in compiler error [C2280](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280).

`CArray`, however, provides the public [`Copy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class#copy) member that copies data from a `CArray` instance into the `CArray` instance on which it is called.

Replacing

```cpp
definition = temp;
```

with

```cpp
definition.Copy(temp);
```

fixes the compiler error and copies values from `temp` into `definition`. Following this line of code, `definition` and `temp` hold the same data.

---

#### Improving ergonomics

Modulo the ambiguity (does `Copy()` copy **from**, or **into** the left-hand side?), there's nothing wrong with explicitly invoking the class member. Ideally, though, it should be possible to augment the interface of a foreign type with custom functionality to allow writing concise code.

Free functions have long been the go-to solution for this in C++, and operators are no exception. Still, for reasons unknown to me, C++ does not allow providing an [assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) (`operator=`) as a free function.

It does allow externally supplying all "compound" assignment operators as free functions, though (such as `operator+=`). With that, we can get close to what we want to write by introducing this:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
inline CArray<T, U>& operator+=(CArray<T, U>& dst, CArray<T, U> const& src)
{
    dst.Append(src);
    return dst;
}
```

With this function template, we can write

```cpp
definition += temp;
```

and at least eliminate the ambiguity by mapping to the conventional *lhs*/*rhs* dichotomy prevalent in C-like languages. This implements "append" functionality (not "copy"). To make "append" and "copy" behave identically, the left-hand side needs to be empty. Call [`RemoveAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class#removeall) beforehand to establish this precondition, if required.

This is not ideal, but at least it is something. It is the best we can do (at the time of writing) without introducing a new type (e.g. by deriving from the `CArray` class template).